# free(): invalid pointer on simple unique_ptr buffer holder

Tags: c++, pointers

I pass this function to Rust, which uses it to allocate a buffer and return its `uint8_t *` pointer:

```
extern "C" uint8_t *cpp_allocate_buffer(size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[size];
    return buffer;
}
```

then, I put this pointer inside this struct that guarantees it's self deleted when it goes out of scope:

```
struct Buffer
{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data;
    size_t len = 0;
    Buffer(CBuffer cBuffer)
    {
        data = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(cBuffer.data);
        len = cBuffer.len;
    }
    Buffer(bool empty)
    {
        data = std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(nullptr);
        this->len = 0;
        this->empty = empty;
    }

    uint8_t *getData()
    {
        return data.get();
    }
    bool empty = false;
};
```

ps: CBuffer is just:

```
   struct CBuffer
    {
        uint8_t *data;
        size_t len;
    };
```

so I do `Buffer b(myCBuffer)`.

But I'm getting

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

right after the destruction of a `shared_ptr` that constains a `shared_ptr<Buffer>`. However the problem happens only in some situations, possibly when the destruction happens on another thread. I'm not sure because I couldn't isolate the problem. Is there something wrong on how I'm deleting this pointer?

Comment: Since you have a `shared_ptr` of `Buffer`, it must mean that this `Buffer` itself must've been allocated in dynamic scope. What is your evidence that this allocation error related to that `uint8_t` pointer, and not the `Buffer` that contains it? The point is that you have absolutely no useful information to go on except that you have undefined behavior that results in memory corruption. It may not even have anything to do, whatsoever, with these objects, but with some other objects created in code that you didn't show.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've putted `std::cout`s on my entire code and discovered that it crashes right after the destruction of  `Buffer` (I've put a log in `~Buffer`). Well, Rust allocates the `uint8_t*` and then passes it immediately to C++ and I put on this function. There's no other code that could be deleting this `uint8_t*`

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs *I've putted std::couts on my entire code and discovered that it crashes right after the destruction of Buffer* -- That still doesn't invalidate what SamV is saying.  You could have corrupted your program long before that crash occurs.  All the crash is showing is where your program *finally* comes apart, and may not even be where the problems actually started.

Comment: Just because a C++ program crashes in any particular place doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. Where the program crashes and why the program crashes are two completely independent things.

Comment: Indeed, the code that received the buffer was expecting it to be terminated with `\0`. Looks like reading outside of the buffer does some crazy things to the code